# Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: image

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, getter

My logcat says that it "Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property : image". Am using firebase database and I have no child named "image" rather I have a child name "Image".

```
public class BlogCV {

public String Image;
public String Title;


public BlogCV() {
}

public BlogCV(String Image, String Title){
    this.Title = Title;
    this.Image = Image;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class should look like this:

```
public class BlogCV {
    public String image, title;

    public BlogCV() {}

    public BlogCV(String image, String title){
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Please see the fields which are now starting with lower cases.

Comment: app doesn't crash anymore but I was unable to get data from database..
after changing my key to lowercase letters (Image to image and Title to title) I am able to get data.


Thanks.. :)

Comment: *firebaser here* Alternatively you can mark the member fields as non-public, so that Firebase only finds the getters. So `private String Image, Title;` will also work.

Comment: After hours of work, I couldn't solve the problem untill see you answer. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

When using other libraries, make sure you follow the Java naming conventions. You should use the name of variables in `camelCase` starting from lowercase letter.

Your question is not clear. But I believe it can be solved by using the name of the variable as `images` and `title`.